# How can I predict which Wicket components will have their tags rendered in the final page?

Tags: wicket

For some Wicket components, if I call `setOutputMarkupId(true)` they warn when they are rendered.

```
Markup id set on a component that is usually not rendered into markup.
```

I'd like to output an id for every component that will actually end up in the HTML in order that I can find them with XPath for testing. How can I predict from class or properties of a `Component` whether it is sensible to `setOutputMarkupId(true)`?

---

More detail - in my `Application` I'm overriding

```
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    addComponentInstantiationListener(new IComponentInstantiationListener() {
        public void onInstantiation(Component component) {
            if (!(component instanceof WebMarkupContainer)) return;
            if (component instanceof WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup) return;
            if (component instanceof Border.BorderBodyContainer) return;
            WebMarkupContainer container = (WebMarkupContainer) component;
            if (container.isTransparentResolver()) return;

            component.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        }});
```

For a sample of pages, this arbitrary gubbins does the trick, but it does seem pretty arbitrary!

Comment: Obviously I don't know the details of the problem you're trying to solve but are you sure this is a good idea? You can use xpath easily without flagging everything up with a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Repeater components like `DataView` and `ListView` don't have their own markup, but repeat the markup with `Item`s. You can check if the component is `instanceof RepeatingView`.

This problem is easily shown by the following, wrong, example:

```
ListView<Person> people = new ListView<Person>("people", list) {
    protected void onPopulateItem(ListItem<Person> item) {
        add(new Label("name", item.getModelObject().getName()));
    }
}
```

Here we don't add the label to the list item, but rather the listview. And that fails. The code should've been:

```
ListView<Person> people = new ListView<Person>("people", list) {
    protected void onPopulateItem(ListItem<Person> item) {
        item.add(new Label("name", item.getModelObject().getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checking for `instanceof RepeatingView` doesn't seem to remove half of the warnings. Are their any nice generic superclasses I should be checking?

Answer (score 1):

Also ignore auto-components (Component.isAuto()).
Such components are for example: `<wicket:container>`, `<wicket:enclosure>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea. I didn't try this ans can't right now...

You could find the components, that will propably be rendered by checking if the are tied to a WicketTag (which are not rendered or at least which are the ones causing this message).

This can be done like this:

```
boolean isGoingToBeRendered (Component component) {
    MarkupStream stream = new MarkupStream(component.getMarkup());
    ComponentTag tag = stream.getTag();
    return (!tag instanceof WicketTag);
}
```

Again: This is no tried solution, just some lines of code hacked into this editor. It's indended as a pointer not as a ready to use piece of code.